# eigenvalue of a positive definite diagonal matrix and an outer product of a vector with itself.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A be diagonal positive definite and B = q*q' - p*p' . Is there anything we can say about the eigenvalues of A + B? Under what conditions, if any, would A + B be positive definite?

Comment: eat yo eigenveggies kids

Comment: If $A,B$ are both positive definite, then so is their sum.

Answer (score 0):

This may help. Theorem:
c positive scalar, A positive definite, cA- bb' is positive definite if and only if b'inv(A)b < c. 
This theorem expresses outer product bb' in terms of inner product.

The above Theorem is attributed to Farebrother, R. W. (1976). Does anyone know any result to prove cA - bb' is negative definite?

Comment: The above Theorem is attributed to Farebrother, R. W. (1976).